# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'url' with arguments '('',)' not found

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to pass URL as a parameter in dynamic URL. The URL contains ? which is making django search for the keys. How do I make Django ignore '?' that are present in my URL.
Custom URL: https://www.amazon.in/Samsung-Galaxy-M12-Storage-Processor/dp/B08XGDN3TZ/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=redmi+9&qid=1622011804&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFZSlE5U0lEUzBFUVQmZW
[prd.Url is passed as a parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OKYf.png)

**TEMPLATE**

```
{% for prd in prds %}
    {{ prd.name }}
    <a href="{% url 'url' prd.Url %}">Click</a>
{% endfor %}
```

**URLS**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('create/', createProfile.as_view(), name='create_profile'),
    path('update/<pk>', UpdateProfile.as_view(), name='update_profile'),
    path('url/<my_url>', url, name='url')
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as indicated in the screenshot you posted, is not caused by the question mark in the URL - the parameters passed to the `{% url %}` template tag are already URL-encoded, as documented [for the reverse function here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse), which means a question mark will be translated to `%3F`.

What is not quoted by the URL tag, however, are the slashes in your URL: something like `http://google.com/?q=term` becomes `http%3A//google.com/%3Fq%3Dterm`. When using the `path` function to construct URL patterns, `url/<my_url>` is translated to a regular expression like `url/(?P<my_url>[^/]+)$`. Note the `[^/]+` part, which means any character other than `/`, at least once. So your URL pattern will not match any URLs that contain slashes.

Instead, you could try to use a `re_path` like this:

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
   ...
   re_path('url/(?P<my_url>.+)', name=..., view=...),
]
```

Here, `.+` will match the whole URL, including the slashes.

Alternatively, you could also pass the URL as a query string parameter, in which case you would need to [do the URL encoding yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode), and adjust the "receiving" view function accordingly.